# How to create windows-based CUDA-enabled docker image?

Tags: python, windows, docker, dockerfile, cuda

I'm new to docker. I created an executable from python script (with `pyinstaller`) that I want to run in docker container. That executable needs CUDA.
I found CUDA-enabled image from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda).
But, these images are for linux. I cannot find CUDA-enabled image for Windows. I'm not clear what should I do and how to proceed. How can I create an CUDA-enabled image where I could run my executable inside the docker container?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.3.1-base-ubuntu20.04

COPY myapp.exe /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["myapp.exe"]
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/gpu-acceleration

Comment: @talonmies, I didn't quite understand how the link helps me. Does it mean that only DirectX is supported from docker container and not Cuda?

Comment: That is what it clearly says.

Comment: OK, so why it was voted to close and downgrade the rating. If I had found this link, I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: The link was the second result when I searched for “docker windows GPU”.

Answer (score -1):

Docker can run on Windows, but it uses Linux-based containers by default. To run Linux containers on Windows, Docker uses a lightweight virtual machine (VM). This means that even though your host machine is Windows, based on the Dockerfile you have provided base image will be  Linux(ubuntu). This is why you typically find Docker images, including CUDA-enabled ones, based on Linux distributions.

Comment: What do you mean by "This means that even though your host machine is Windows, the Docker containers you're running are based on Linux."? Are you saying that whatever image I use is Linux based? It doesn't make sense as there are clearly windows-based images available.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. Microsoft package and release a family of Windows OS based docker containers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-base-images and make then available through docker hub https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).